# Nutch: Job Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, web-crawler, nutch

i have problem while running nutch for inject
following is the command i am running

bin/nutch inject bin/crawl/crawldb bin/urls

after running above command, gets following error

```
Injector: starting at 2014-04-02 13:02:29
Injector: crawlDb: bin/crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: bin/urls/seed.txt
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 2
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 0
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: overwrite: false
Injector: update: false
Injector: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:294)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:306)
```

I am running nutch for the first time.
i have checked solr, nutch are installed properly.

below details are from log file

```
java.io.IOException: The temporary job-output directory file:/usr/share/apache-nutch-1.8/bin/crawl/crawldb/1639805438/_temporary doesn't exist!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.getWorkPath(FileOutputCommitter.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.getTaskOutputPath(FileOutputFormat.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(MapFileOutputFormat.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.<init>(ReduceTask.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:398)
2014-04-02 12:54:46,251 ERROR crawl.Injector - Injector: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:294)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:306)
```

Comment: According to your logs you have problems with permission. Probably this job doesn't have permission to create folder inside /usr/...

Comment: @Mysterion Thank you for response..as u suggested i have change the permissions..but still getting the same error.

Comment: Solved the above error.

Comment: But nutch is not fetching urls from seed file..can anyone help?

Comment: how you solve it? Plz update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was using bin/nutch inject bin/crawl/crawldb bin/urls command to inject

instead of bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb bin/urls

Which solves the error.

and for fetching urls i have done changes to regex-urlfilter.txt file, now am able to fetch the urls.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any syntax errors in any of your nutch config files.